# How to show choices of field in another table(model) value?

Tags: django, django-models

How to show choices of field in another table value?
I want to Nutritionalkey show on the NutritionalValues choice field

```
class Nutritionalkey(models.Model):
key = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.key

class NutritionalValues(models.Model):
  key = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Nutritionalkey.key)
  value=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
  product=models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, blank=True)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = 'NutritionalValues'
      verbose_name = 'NutritionalValue'

  def __unicode__(self):
      return '%s %s' % (self.product.productName,self.key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices) says:

> But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re
>   probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey.

You should then have:

```
class NutritionalValues(models.Model):
    key = models.ForeignKey(Nutritionalkey)
    ...
```